# OpenTBS and Special Characters (PHP)

Tags: php, ms-word, tinybutstrong, opentbs

I'm using OpenTBS to modify word templates from PHP. Basically I need to update strings in a word document from values that I have in a MySQL database. It is working well, however when I have special characters such as é, à, ô, it outputs a sequence of weird caracters.

For example the é gives me Ã©.

Anybody knows how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, OpenTBS assumes that the data to be merged are Ascii encoded.
It the data is UTF-8 encoded, then you have to specify it when loading the template.

Example:

```
$TBS->LoadTemplate('document.docx', OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
```

You also have to check that your PHP script is UTF-8 encoded.

More details are given [in the manual](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/opentbs/tbs_plugin_opentbs.html#loadtemplate).

Answer (score 0):

Its a character encoding issue. 
Change your page to utf-8

```
See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```